# How do you remove header and footer in Word 2011?

Tags: ms-office, macos

I have found the ribbon/menu option where you can work with your header and footer but according to Google there should be a "None" option you should use if you don't want any header or footer at all - and I can't find this option.

This is how it looks when I click the Header button in Header and Footer ribbon:

[image]

And this is how my document look like:

[image]

How do I get rid of this header?

Comment: Is there a reason can’t you just leave the header and footer blank?

Comment: It wastes space.

Comment: Does it prevent you from moving the upper and lower margins?

Comment: Just wondering if you've had a chance to try the steps in my answer? Did this work or are you still having problems?

Comment: @Monomeeth I am not sure if it works. How do you verify that there is no header?

Comment: Ah, well, usually whatever is in the header is visible in a faint colour above where you're actually able to type text (or below in the case of footers). However, you may need to make sure your document is in an appropriate view (e.g. in the Print Layout view) in order to see what's in your header/footer. If it's empty then you know nothing is there. The other option would be to print a page of the document to make sure that no header and/or footer prints out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I've ever seen the *None* option you're referring to. Even in Ms Word 2016 there's no such option, but you do get a *Remove Header* option.

As for MS Word 2011, the only way I've ever been able to remove a header is as follows:

1. Double-click on the header within your document
2. Go to Edit > Select All (or just press the <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> keyboard shortcut)
3. Now press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key on your keyboard
4. Click the Close button on the header (see image below):

   [image]

Now your Header will be gone.